# PHP $_REQUEST error

Tags: php, request

For some reason my `$_REQUEST` variable does not get the information I need it to get, this is the code I have got.

```
<?php
  if($_REQUEST["join"] != null){
      echo "Activated.";
  }
?>
<a href="?join=1">Join</a>
```

but for some reason this does not work, the page never echos Activated.

Comment: Post your `var_dump($_REQUEST)`.

Comment: and what about `$_GET` ?

Comment: So what would that line be? I'm sorry I have never used that.

Comment: @rikesh var_dump actually :)

Comment: Try using that. Put that code above your if condition & post here.

Comment: I tried $_GET but still no luck.

Comment: Question is not clear.You can use !empty instead of null

Comment: Tested your code and got the word "Activated" that echo'ed once I clicked on it, so something else is breaking your code. Are you running this on a local machine or web? Plus... might be a silly question but I'll ask it anyway, does your file have the `.php` extension? Or what exactly happens when you click on the link? And I mean "exactly".

Comment: No it does not have the .php extension(I think that might be the problem), and I click it the page reloads with no change.

Comment: that is exactly the problem. `.php` files run off a webserver, while an `.html` file runs off a web "browser". Change it to `.php` and try again

Comment: Ok, so where are we at, it's working I'll bet, now that you've renamed it. @user3156054

Comment: Not yet, I cannot remove the extension due to the .htaccess. I could make it a form if that was the only needed thing on the page. I could try to put it in a new founder, then the .php extension would be back and I could then use the methods I have been told.

Comment: If there is any PHP inside your file, it will still need to have the `.php` extension. However, you can use `.htaccess` to tell Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP; that's an option. But either way, your file will still need to be using PHP and not the browser as the interpreter. @user3156054

Comment: you can use isset or empty to check the condition and do the things.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["join"]))
{

    echo "Activated.";

}

?>
<a href="?join=1">Join</a>
```

First time it willn't print echo because server didn't get any `$_REQUEST`. But after click on join it will print the echo string. That `$_REQUEST` was undefined. so use [isset](http://www.php.net/isset)  that server will check is the `$_REQUEST` set or not and wouldn't print any warring.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Isset](http://www.php.net/isset)**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_REQUEST["join"])){
      echo "Activated.";
  }
?>

<a href="?join=1">Join</a>
```